# echo bash variable as text

Tags: bash, variables, echo

I am trying to echo a var as text and not parse it. Everything I have tried and searched for just seems to show me how to echo the variable and not the variable text only.

Note the code below is just what I have as basic echo. I have tried \"$ARG1$\" etc with this line.

```
echo "command[runcmd]=sudo service $ARG1$ restart" >> testfile
```

What I want is for it to show

```
command[runcmd]=sudo service $ARG1$ restart
```

BUT what it ends up as is

```
command[runcmd]=sudo service $ restart
```

I know this is a syntax error on my part but I can't seem to find the proper way even in the in MAN pages. Maybe I am missing something.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to escape to dollar sign: `echo "command[runcmd]=sudo service \$ARG1$ restart" >> testfile` It's under the Quoting section in the bash manual: ... (\) is the escape character. It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use single quotes: they prevent variable substitution:

```
echo 'command[runcmd]=sudo service $ARG1$ restart'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes (') instead of double ("):

```
echo 'command[runcmd]=sudo service $ARG1$ restart' >> testfile
```